Websocket + Nestjs + this.server.of() is not a function
I am trying to create a browser multi player game using nestjs and websockets. At the core the game is a 4 player card game, I need to manage state server side so that a) players cannot see each others cards in the request, b) if the database was breached the cards are also not stored there.
Currently my user clicks a play button where they hit a static endpoint that either creates a new 'game' or adds them to an open game. The response sends back a game object which I use to then connect the websocket /game/:id
Here is my websocket:
@WebSocketGateway({
    namespace: /\/game\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/, // Dynamically scoped by game ID
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
    },
})
export class GameGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
    @WebSocketServer() server: Server

    constructor(
        protected _jwtService: JwtService,
        protected _gameService: GameService,
    ) {}

    afterInit() {
        console.log('Gateway initialized')
    }

    // Handle player connection
    async handleConnection(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
        client.nsp.emit('player_connected', {})


    }

    // Handle player disconnection
    async handleDisconnect(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
        console.log('Disconnection')
    }

    // Emit an event to the specific game namespace when the registration is closed
    @OnEvent('game.registration-closed')
    handleGameReady(game: Game) {
        /**
            * TODO: Begin Setup of game
            */

            this.server.of(`game/${game._id}`).emit('pregame', game)
    }
}

I did not want to create a single /game websocket and divide into rooms as I need to have scoped state for each game and I dont think it scales very well managing all the rooms states inside 1 object. Therefore I opted for a dynamically named gateway /\/game\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/,
My problem in my service when the game is full, i change the status to closed and emit an event that registration is closed and we can move to the next step
if (game.players.length === 4) {
    console.log('Hello')
    this._emitter.emit('game.registration-closed', game)
}

I can see this event in my gateway
@OnEvent('game.registration-closed')
handleGameReady(game: Game) {
    /**
     * TODO: Begin Setup of game
     */

        this.server.of(`game/${game._id}`).emit('pregame', game)
}

However when I try and emit this message to the connected players I get this.server.of is not a function
I am not using rooms so I cannot use this.server.to or I get this.children.forEach cannot read properties of undefined

sounds similar

I already have the decorator - the error might be similar but the cause seems different, maybe because I have it wrapped in event listener ?

I think you either will need to use rooms or manage dynamically the created namespaces, and for scalability and simplicity i suggest using rooms

First Reason,
The problem with your code might be that you are trying to emit a message to the WebSocket namespace (/game/:id) using this.server.of(...), which you have created dynamically. Anyway you are encountering an error: "this.server.of is not a function", and this error mainly occurs because the method .of() may not be recognized or might not be available in the version of the WebSocket server which you are using.
Another possible reason,
Because when you emit inside an event listener then the context of this.server may not set up properly or also may not include dynamically created namespaces.Thus this might be causing the error this.server.of as not a function.
In order to get the issue resolved it is better to manage the state using rooms within a single Web Socket gateway and avoiding to create separate namespace.
I am mentioning below the proper corrected code for each and every step which you want, kindly take the reference from here properly and make the new changes as per your further requirements.
First create a WebSocket:

    import {
        WebSocketGateway,
        WebSocketServer,
        OnGatewayInit,
        OnGatewayConnection,
        OnGatewayDisconnect,
        ConnectedSocket,
        SubscribeMessage,
        MessageBody,
    } from '@nestjs/websockets';
    import { Server, Socket } from 'socket.io';
    import { GameService } from './game.service';
    import { OnEvent } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';
    
    @WebSocketGateway({
        namespace: '/game',
        cors: {
            origin: '*',
        },
    })
    export class GameGateway implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect {
        @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
    
        constructor(private _gameService: GameService) {}
    
        afterInit() {
            console.log('Gateway initialized');
        }
    
        async handleConnection(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
            console.log('Player connected:', client.id);
        }
    
        async handleDisconnect(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket) {
            console.log('Player disconnected:', client.id);
        }
    
        @SubscribeMessage('join_game')
        async handleJoinGame(@ConnectedSocket() client: Socket, @MessageBody() gameId: string) {
            console.log(`Player ${client.id} joining game ${gameId}`);
            client.join(gameId);
            this._gameService.addPlayerToGame(gameId, client.id);
        }
    
        @OnEvent('game.registration-closed')
        handleGameReady(game: any) {
            console.log(`Game ${game._id} registration closed. Emitting pregame.`);
            this.server.to(game._id).emit('pregame', game);
        }
    }


Now Implement your game service such as:

        import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
        import { EventEmitter2 } from '@nestjs/event-emitter';
        
        @Injectable()
        export class GameService {
            private games: Map<string, any> = new Map();
        
            constructor(private _emitter: EventEmitter2) {}
        
            createGame(gameId: string) {
                if (!this.games.has(gameId)) {
                    this.games.set(gameId, {
                        id: gameId,
                        players: [],
                        status: 'open',
                    });
                    console.log(`Game ${gameId} created.`);
                }
            }
            addPlayerToGame(gameId: string, playerId: string) {
                const game = this.games.get(gameId);
                if (game && game.status === 'open') {
                    game.players.push(playerId);
                    console.log(`Player ${playerId} added to game ${gameId}.`);
                    if (game.players.length === 4) {
                        game.status = 'closed';
                        this._emitter.emit('game.registration-closed', game);
                        console.log(`Game ${gameId} registration closed.`);
                    }
                }
            }
        
            getGame(gameId: string) {
                return this.games.get(gameId);
            }
        
            removePlayerFromGame(gameId: string, playerId: string) {
                const game = this.games.get(gameId);
                if (game) {
                    game.players = game.players.filter(id => id !== playerId);
                    console.log(`Player ${playerId} removed from game ${gameId}.`);
                }
            }
        }
    

I will also advice you to add a Game Controller to manage the game creation and addition of new player. If you wish then the code will be something like:

    import { Controller, Post, Body } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { GameService } from './game.service';
    
    @Controller('game')
    export class GameController {
        constructor(private readonly gameService: GameService) {}
    
        @Post('create')
        createGame(@Body('gameId') gameId: string) {
            this.gameService.createGame(gameId);
            return { message: `Game ${gameId} created.` };
        }
    
        @Post('add-player')
        addPlayerToGame(@Body('gameId') gameId: string, @Body('playerId') playerId: string) {
            this.gameService.addPlayerToGame(gameId, playerId);
            return { message: `Player ${playerId} added to game ${gameId}.` };
        }
    }


Use these codes properly it integrates all of your functions and resolve the queries and still if you face any difficulties then kindly let me know.
